# What is the effect of this XPATH expression?

Tags: xpath

What happens when I apply `following-sibling::*[1]` **to the last child?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What happens when I apply
>   `following-sibling::*[1]` to the last
>   child?

**Answer**: it gets evaluate to an empty node-set, because there is no more following siblings.

If you want to get the following sibling of the context node or following sibling of context node parent otherwise, the rigth axis is `following`, as in:

```
following::*[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It will get you the first sibling to the current node.

Here is an example:

```
<Root>
   <Div id="Hey">
      Test1
   </Div>
   <Div>
      Test2
   </Div>
   <Div>
      Test3
   </Div>
</Root>
```

XPath:

```
/Root/Div[@id = 'Hey']/following-sibling::*[1]
```

`/Root/Div[@id = 'Hey']` will get you the `Div` with `id=Hey` and `/following-sibling::*[1]` will then get you the first sibling so in total you would get the `Div` with the text "Test2".

**Update:** I apologize (see comment), but this: `/Root/Div[3]/following-sibling::*[1]` will just return a empty list. (`Div[3]` is the last child)

Comment: **-1** The question asked what it did when applied to the _last_ child